# Creating HTML page linked to a video database

Tags: html, sql, database

I have been charged by my family to organize the 'family memories' that is creating an access page (which I image being a web page) which would link to the photos, and videos, each of them being 'tagged' such as with the name of the person that took the picture, the location, the date etc...

I have no idea where to start. I thought that SQL and HTML can be a solution but I am not sure whether I am completely wrong or not.

Does someone have an idea?

Kind regards,

Unic0

Answer (score 0):

Yes my friend, don´t try to reinvent the wheel. Go to wordpress.org (or .com) and find a nice portfolio template that has all those needs, like tagging and fancy slideshows, lightboxes, etc.

Comment: Oh ! Okay ! Thank you very much ! I'll look into that ! Do you know if I then could access it offline ? Like have the page accessing the local sources from a hard drive as the html page would then be just a front page for the pictures etc.. ?

Comment: You could but why would you do it? an online server takes all complications out of it. 
Take a look at this site I did in wordpress, a couple of ways to show pictures 
https://www.filmingperu.com/projects/ ->projects
https://www.filmingperu.com/portfolio-item/tinajani-canyon/ -> locations

Everything is online, and uploading pictures is as easy as just grabbing them all and throwing them in.